# mySQL JSON_TABLE query to return nested data

Tags: mysql, json

I want to take the data from here:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/usnistgov/oscal-content/master/examples/ssp/json/ssp-example.json

which I've pulled into a mySQL database called "ssp_models" into a JSON column called 'json_data', and I need to retrieve the 'name' and 'type' values from the 'parties' node which is nested 3 levels deep.

I've been trying to follow this blog-post about how to retrieve nested data:  https://mysqlserverteam.com/json_table-the-best-of-both-worlds/

and I am struggling with the nesting selection process.  Obviously this is not the right way:

```
SELECT "system-security-plan.*" 
FROM ssp_models, 
     JSON_TABLE(json_data, '$.metadata[*]' COLUMNS (
          NESTED PATH '$.parties[*]' COLUMNS (
                name VARCHAR(140)  PATH '$.name',
                type VARCHAR(140)  PATH '$.type')
     )) parties;
```

Presently, I get nothing back:

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0024 seconds.)

It *seems* like it should be close to working, as I am pulling everything from the "system-security-plan" node and querying based on the metadata -> parties nodes to retrieve 'name' and 'type'.  What am I missing?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please make a ddl from your table, so that we can test it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need NESTED PATH because the JSON only contains objects-within-objects from the top level down to the array you want to become rows of your json table:

```
SELECT parties.name, parties.type
FROM ssp_models,
     JSON_TABLE(json_data, '$."system-security-plan".metadata.parties[*]' COLUMNS (
                name VARCHAR(140)  PATH '$.name',
                type VARCHAR(140)  PATH '$.type')
     ) parties
```

Output:

```
+---------------------------------+--------------+
| name                            | type         |
+---------------------------------+--------------+
| Enterprise Asset Owners         | organization |
| Enterprise Asset Administrators | organization |
| Legal Department                | organization |
| IT Department                   | organization |
| Acme Corp                       | organization |
+---------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: That's it!  This is perfect.  It works like a charm.

Comment: Can you tell me what the query would look like if I wanted to 'insert' a new name/type into the 'parties' node?

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66288314/mysql-json-document-store-method-for-inserting-data-into-node-3-levels-deep. New question asked